# VIsual Studio 2010 Show .vb and .designer.vb file for an aspx file

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

In most of my projects (VB.NET or C#) using Visual Studio 2010, I can "expand" an .aspx file to show the related .vb and .designer.vb files. In a few other projects I can't. I can edit by  right-clicking view code but prefer the other method.

Is there a VS setting to enable this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Solution Explorer, there's a button at the top, 2nd from right, called Show All Files. If you click on it, it will show you your vb and designer files

Comment: I had thought that was for only files that exist outside of the project so I didn't even try it. But it works, thanks.